# Why are these Webdriver tests running with my own Mocha-Protractor tests?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

While running my entire suite of tests, many tests from the WebDriver module are also running.

Note that they fail. Mostly for this reason:

`ReferenceError: expect is not defined`

My own tests run fine, and succeed and pass on their own it seems.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Screenshots included:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you found the reason for your problem. Please click the checkmark icon to the left of your answer to "accept" it--otherwise this question keeps showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The tests that were being run aren't *supposed* to be published to npm, however:

In my issue, the `webdriver-manager` specs were only run when the conf file globbed `./**/**/*_spec.js`

The maintainers found:

> The TypeScript files are being transpiled to *.js and the built/spec directory is being published.

This was fixed.